# How to filter 0s using Javascript array filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I need to get new array which includes all the 0-s from the input array(arr).

```
var a=arr.filter(function(val){
if((val===0)){
return val;
}
})
```

for some reason this returns an empty array, while for example if I try to get all the non 0-s in the array

```
var a=arr.filter(function(val){

    if(!(val===0)){
    return val;
    }
    })
```

this code works perfectly fine.

why?

Comment: The callback is supposed to return `true` or `false` *for every value*, indicating whether to keep or filter the value…!

Comment: Do you want the indexes of entries where the value is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets step through these but first we need to look at definition of truthy/falsy

> From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) :  In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that is considered  true when encountered in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy (i.e., except for false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN).

---

**Your first example:**

```
if((val===0)){
   return val;
}
```

The first one only has a return for zeros and you return those zeros. Zero is falsy so they are excluded.

There is no return for the other values and a function with no explicit return statement always returns undefined...which is falsy.

So both conditions return falsy and result is empty array

**Second example**

```
if(!(val===0)){
   return val;
}
```

Return for anything other than zero and return the value.

All non-zero numbers are truthy so you get all of those in your array.

The zeros are getting excluded because of no explicit return returning undefined again

---

How to filter to return non zero values with a proper true/false?

```
 return val !== 0;
```

Comment: For completeness, what OP actually wants is `arr.filter(i => i === 0)`.